# how to configure SSL when self hosting Web api in https in local machine

Tags: ssl, asp.net-web-api, https, self-hosting

I want to build a desktop app, which accepts triggers from the browser (my web application runs in https). As a solution i have implemented self hosting web api with OWIN which uses self signed certificate.

Registered the certificate for https using netsh command

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:4443 certhash=‎40514d4576059d0c1c205c7b820cc0a407915b65 appid={163ea903-b9fd-4019-9c5c-7cdf158111a6}
```

Now when i try to send http request, browser complains that the certificate is not valid.

```
https://localhost:4443/api/download
```

Is it possible to create/buy valid certificates for localhost? (my app will be running on different user machines) Is there any other way i can solve my situation ( solving browser to local app communication)?

Comment: Why do you want to use https with localhost ? it's already considered as a secure origin, even with http: https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features

Comment: because my web application runs in https and we cannot make a call to http from https.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18443181/configuring-ssl-on-asp-net-self-hosted-web-api

Answer (score 0):

Basically i found that we cannot self host webapi in https. Because we cannot get a SSL for localhost, browser will not allow http request to that.